# Issues with using sqlite3 with electron on Mac OS

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

I am trying to include the sqlite3 package into my electron project. I  I get this error:

have done postinstall. It runs correctly on nodejs.

node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/electron-v4.0-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 69. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with using sqlite on my developing app, The problem comes from Electron that's change the NODE_MODULE_VERSION to 69 refer to githup issue page to find more info https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/16687

I don't find a really working way to solve the problem for now just downgrade the electron and sqlite version to an older version should solve the problem and build the native module.